# eclipse RCP for the web

Tags: eclipse-rcp, eclipse-rap

My client has lots of eclipse RCP applications and wants to convert them to web applications with least possible effort.

Is there any alternative to eclipse RAP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Least possible effort in conversion of an RCP application to WEB? Definitly RAP.